# How to allow sub site access ONLY to FBA users in SharePoint Server 2013?

Tags: permissions, forms-authentication, sharepoint-2013

I have a site called Home and sub site called Tutorials under Home in SharePoint 2013 as shown below:

1. Home
2. Home/Tutorials

The Tutorials sub site has unique site permission.

I have implemented Codeplex's FBA Pack for Forms Based Authentication and it works fine. 
I want some FBA users to allow access only to Tutorials sub site but not the parent Home site. This works perfectly with AD users but not with FBA users. The sub site is available only if FBA user has permission in parent site. If the FBA user is removed from parent site and if s/he is still in sub site, the access is not possible.

Help Please.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a "real" solution to this problem, but I know that it is related to the Site Collection Master Page gallery. Basically, the FBA user has access to the site, but does not have access to the resources in the Site Collection Master Page gallery, which is used to render the SharePoint pages.

I tried to give unique permissions on the Site Collection gallery and then turned it off (inherited again from the Parent Site), and then, somehow, I could get FBA users to see the subsite. I don't know if this will stick, but I thought it might work for you. If not, at least you know what the cause of the issue is, and can come up with a permissions solution that works for you.

UPDATE: It could also be a Site Asset linked from a list in the Parent Site. For example, a logo that is carried over from the Parent Site when you create a new Sub Site. Changing that to point to an asset in the Sub Site instead of the parent Site should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I was able to get around this issue by also adding the user to the Style Resource Readers group in Sharepoint 2013. The problem must have been that the user did not have access to the Master Page. Adding the user to this group did not give the user access to any of the higher level sites only the subsite.

Answer (score 0):

The issue where FBA users cannot be added to sub-sites unless they exist in the root site has been fixed in version 1.3.4.  [Link to FBA Pack Releases](http://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/releases/view/120338)